# Getting Intermittent ADB2C "Bad Request" error

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, aad-b2c

I have a sign up custom policy and we get an intermittent "Bad Request" error after the submit button is clicked. I read somewhere that it could be that the request is too long but I am not sure if this is the same error. When page is refreshed it usually resolves and it goes to the redirect uri and processes successfully. Application insights logs don't have anything.  How can I know what the specific cause?

[console screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNux7.png)

Comment: Submit button on what page?

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT submit button on the sign up policy.  We get a bad request error instead of redirecting to the redirect uri. This happens intermittently.

Comment: You need to find some pattern for anyone to offer advice.

Answer (score 0):

There's an open issue [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/35686603-unhandled-bad-request-when-login-page-is-left-open), where B2C doesn't handle an internal error properly if the page is left open for > ~4 hours.  Does this match your scenario?